# TypeError: Cannot read property 'console' of null

Tags: javascript

Here's the guilty snippet extracted from a third party lib :

```
function hasConsoleLogger() {
    return window.console && window.console.log;
}
```

Nothing fancy, but it surprisingly returns :
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'console' of null`

It's executed in a browser context (Chrome) so no Node.js non-window stuff involved.

I've checked for potential malicious `delete window` or `window = null` without success.

The application where this bug occurs runs with Friendly iFrames, and document.write() calls.

Unfortunately I can't provide any demo link of the issue.

So I guess my question is **"How could the window object be nullified or unreachable by mistake in a browser?"**

Comment: I just tried to do: `window=null;`; it silently failed in Chrome. IMO, it is smart enough to prevent such assignment.

Comment: is it in global scope or inside a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a window is closed, Chrome first sets `window.console` is to `null`, then `window`.

The following code will reliably reproduce the error, by creating a function which references `window` from a different context:

```
var w = window.open('/');
// Using document.write to run code in the context of the other window
w.document.write('<script>opener.func = function(){return window;};</script>');
w.close();
// Naive timer to wait for Garbage collection
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(func() === null); // true
}, 100);
```